# Firebase Sorting

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

Basically, I have an app on Firebase. The thing is, when Firebase sorts the data, instead of a chronological order, it muddles the data.

When I went online and search why, I found that it was because I was using the snapshot.value instead of snapshot.children.

However, I'm not completely sure how to change the code accordingly, could someone help?

Here is the code:

```
func retrieveChatLog() {

        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("chats").child(chatID).observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in

        let chats = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]

        self.messages.removeAll()

        for (_, value) in chats {

            if let sender = value["sender"], let message = value["message"], let senderID = value["senderUID"], let date = value["date"] {

                let messageToShow = Message()

                messageToShow.message = message as! String

                messageToShow.sender = sender as! String

                messageToShow.senderUID = senderID as! String

                let formatter = DateFormatter()

                formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"

                let curDate = formatter.date(from: date as! String)

                messageToShow.date = curDate as! Date

                if messageToShow.senderUID != "" {
                    self.messages.append(messageToShow)
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().removeAllObservers()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't because you use snapshot.value. You can use .value or .childAdded. The problem is, if you use .value, you don't want to cast the snapshots to a dictionary because dictionaries don't preserve order. Instead, you're going to want to cast to an array to preserve order. Here's one way you could resolve this:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("chats").child(chatID).observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
    let chats = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot]
    self.messages.removeAll()

    for chat in chats {
        if let value = chat.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            if let sender = value["sender"], let message = value["message"], let senderID = value["senderUID"], let date = value["date"] {

                let messageToShow = Message()
                messageToShow.message = message as! String
                messageToShow.sender = sender as! String
                messageToShow.senderUID = senderID as! String
                let formatter = DateFormatter()
                formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
                let curDate = formatter.date(from: date as! String)
                messageToShow.date = curDate as! Date
                if messageToShow.senderUID != "" {
                    self.messages.append(messageToShow)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
FIRDatabase.database().reference().removeAllObservers()
```

}

Comment: It gave SIGABRT on line where snapshot.value is cast as [FIRDataSnapshot]

Comment: My bad! It should have said snapshot.children.allObjects, not value. Should be fixed now.

Comment: I got another SIGABRT, but this time it said 'Could not cast value of type '_NSCFConstantString' to 'NSDictionary', but on the line that says chat.value as! [String : AnyObject]

Comment: same line? Because this is exactly how I do it in my app

Comment: Its not the same line... It is this one 'let value = chat as! [String : AnyObject]'

Comment: Thanks.. Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Change this line
`FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("chats").child(chatID).observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in...`

To this
`FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("chats").child(chatID).observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in`

Answer (score 0):

There is an accepted answer but I wanted to provide another solution that may be a bit tighter and more expandable.

It starts with a class to hold the messages. In this case I am keeping just the firebase key and timestamp but other vars could easily be added. You'll note the timestamp var that is read from Firebase in the same format: dd.mm.yy. This would be useful for sorting if needed. Also note that if you want to display a nicely formatted mm/dd/yyyy format, it's available though the formattedDate computed property.

The messagesArray is an array of MessageClass objects which can be used as a datasource for a tableView for example.

Finally, the loadMessages function to load in all of the messages. As mentioned in the other answer, casting the Snapshot to a dictionary loses ordering guarantee. However, if we iterate over the snapshot directly, the ordering stays intact.

```
class MessageClass {
    var timestamp: String
    var fbKey: String
    var formattedDate: String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
        let d = formatter.date(from: timestamp)

        let outputFormattter = DateFormatter()
        outputFormattter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
        let finalDate = outputFormattter.string(from: d!)

        return finalDate
    }

    init(withSnap: DataSnapshot ) {
        let snapDict = withSnap.value as! [String: AnyObject]
        self.timestamp = snapDict["timestamp"] as! String
        self.fbKey = withSnap.key
    }
}

var messagesArray = [MessageClass]()

func doButton0Action() {

    let messagesRef = self.ref.child("messages")
    messagesRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let m = MessageClass(withSnap: snap)
            self.messagesArray.append(m)
        }
        for msg in self.messagesArray { //test code to print the array once loaded
            print("key: \(msg.fbKey)  date: \(msg.formattedDate)")
        }
    })
 }
```

This code is very verbose and could be condensed considerably but it's very readable. (it needs guards and error checking as well).

I would strongly encourage you to store your timestamps in a

> yyyymmddhhmmss

format in firebase. It lends itself to sorting / querying

Also, as a side-note, instead of relying on the date the node was created (by key) to keep your ordering, consider leveraging the timestamp when reading in the nodes using .order(by: timestamp). That will guarantee they are always in the correct order even if messages are changed around or the keys are modified.